# Puppeteer crawling above 8000 sub pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So i am attempting to crawl webshops to get a specific id (the so called EAM id) for all of their products. To do this i am using Puppeteer.

i created the following function:

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        console.log("Iterating through array " + index +  " Of " +array.length);

        await callback(array[index], index, array)
    }
}
```

Now then i created the following script:

```
    await asyncForEach(productsToview, async function (productPage,index, arr) {
    if (productPage.indexOf("url") >= 0) {
        await page.goto(productPage);
        await page.waitForSelector('#site-wrapper');
        await page.click('#product-read-more-specs');
        await page.click('#tab-specs-trigger');
        const productToSave = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const $ = window.$;
            let product = {
                title: $('.product-title').text(),
                EAN: $('.spec-section').last().find('td').last().text(),
                price: $('.product-price-container').text().replace(/\s/g, '')
            };
            return product;
        });
        resultArray.push(productToSave);
    }
});

console.log(resultArray);
```

Now this actually works, however, it is incredibly slow. Each page takes roughly around 3 - 5 seconds and since I have 8000 pages I have to wait for around 10 hours for it to complete.

So my question is, is there a faster way to do it when we are talking about this many pages?

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1422 (block images etc ectc might speed up quite a bit) or this in the API docs https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Subjective solution:** Use multiple tabs/pages and split the whole list into 10 or so parts. It will put strain on the CPU/net etc resources but the scraping should be faster. Not to mention the website might probably mark you as spam for browsing 8000 pages in a short time.

To get this working, you will need several different pieces,

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11764168/6161265) is a snippet to chunk the array into several pieces.
- Then you can use a new tab for each part or page. Each with it's own Promise returning the result.
- Finally a database to store all data asynchronously (preferred) or `Promise.all()` to return result once everything is finished.

It's subjective, and I cannot share the whole solution step by step with code for now but if you put the solution into action, it should be enough.